# How to target an element that has been rendered in a for loop - VUE

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to target an element through a ref/ID that has been rendered within a for loop within Vue? The for loop I have, renders different amounts of elements each time, these elements are all hidden at first, but when one is opened I want a way of grabbing that opened element through an ID or ref so I can read the height of it when opened.

An example of something I thought would work is this. When the condition for foo is true, it will show the element (this part works), but I also want to add the ref 'bar', only when that condition for foo is true. I understand that I am using a ref like a class here, but I thought it would display what I am trying to achieve.

```
<div v-show="foo === 'foo_' + name" :ref="{'bar':(foo === 'foo_' + name)}">
```

Answer (score 0):

try computed property for this

```
<div v-show="foo === 'foo_' + name" :ref="getRefName">
```

Assuming that either `name` or `foo` is the iteration element, you can pass it as argument to the computed property if necessary
and inside computed

```
computed: {
  getRefName() {
   // Below is how you deal with arguments
   return arg => {
    if(condition) return 'some String';
   }
  }
}
```

**New Edit**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
    check: true
  },
  computed: {
   getRefName() {
     return item => {
      if(this.check) return `foo_${item.id}`;
     }
   }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(result, index) in results" :key="index">
    <input type="text" type="file" :ref="getRefName(result)" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It hasn't quite worked but I fear that is because I didn't explain myself properly. Maybe if I word the question differently it would help? I have several variably sized objects coming in using a for loop. I need to get the height of the tallest of them objects the for loop has created. Not even necessarily the tallest, all the others will be 0, I just need the height of the one that isn't 0 (the element that is opened). Is there a better way to do it than this?

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. Check now I have added a working example